# Cannot verify Lets encrypt certificate Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ssl, wget, letsencrypt

I'm running `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS \n \l` which is updated as of today. However, any time I try and `wget` something, this error pops up:

```
# wget --verbose wops.cc
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2022-01-19 11:37:51--  https://wops.cc/
Resolving wops.cc (wops.cc)... 195.201.26.102, 2a01:4f8:1c1c:a588::1
Connecting to wops.cc (wops.cc)|195.201.26.102|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify wops.cc's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to wops.cc insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

`apt install ca-certificates` says I've got the latest version, plus running `update-ca-certificates -f -v` and `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` shows no errors.

EDIT: This looks like the site is the problem, but it's happening with pretty much any recent site, here's another example.

```
 wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-install.sh && bash openvpn-install.sh
--2022-01-19 13:53:01--  https://git.io/vpn
Resolving git.io (git.io)... 54.162.128.250, 54.157.58.70, 18.205.36.100, ...
Connecting to git.io (git.io)|54.162.128.250|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify git.io's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to git.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The server isn't sending any intermediate CA certificates in the chain.  Your client (`wget`) knows of all the trust-anchors (the Root CAs) and the server is sending the wops.cc certificate, but there will be another certificate in the chain.  That's the 'CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US' certificate.  Without it, the client can't join the dots.